# when you use jhipster --skipserver option, what are the different options you can use for authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, jhipster

I am using jhipster --skip-server option to create a client only application. I want to find out what are the different options for auth and db I can use. I tried using the
jhipster --skips-server --db --auth=jwt to get JWT authentication. 
What are the other options I can use, is there a list, what if I want to use the Okta. And when it comes to DB how does it impact my angular code? Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

For authentication, you will want to use `oauth2` in order to use Okta.  The list of authentication options is `jwt`, `session`, `uaa`, `oauth2`. For a full list of all available app options, see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#available-application-options

The database affects your Angular code minimally.  The only difference would be with the NoSQL type:

- Entity primary keys may be strings instead of longs
- Relationships don't work as well with NoSQL (Mongo recently added support)